# Passing variable from a script to my python email script to be output in in mail under quotation

Tags: shell, python, email, variables, smtp

how do i pass variable (missing file) $file from a script to my python email script in the body message.
script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
file = abc.txt
echo "the following" ${file} "are missing"
pythonEmail.py
```

pythonEmail.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import smtplib
sender = 'me@test.com'
receivers = ['you@test.com']
message = """From: myself<me@test.com>
To: you@test.com'
Subject: missing files
$file
"""
try:
   smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP("localhost")
   smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)
   print ("Successfully sent email")
except SMTPException:
   print ("Error: unable to send email")
```

Comment: I think this is more of a Python question, rather than a Linux question, because you simply want to get external data into a python script. A few options I can think of: 1) Do an `echo $files | python script.py` and have the script read `sys.stdin`. 2) Have the shell script write to a file, and read the same file from the python script. 3) Pass the values as command-line arguments to the script, and use `sys.argv` to read them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not much more than what @Haxiel commented:

script.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=abc.txt
echo "the following" ${file} "are missing"
pythonEmail.py $file
```

pythonEmail.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import smtplib
import sys

sender = 'me@test.com'
receivers = ['you@test.com']
message = """\
From: myself<me@test.com>
To: you@test.com
Subject: missing files

%s""" % (sys.argv[1])

try:
   smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP("localhost")
   smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)
   print ("Successfully sent email")
except SMTPException:
   print ("Error: unable to send email")
```

Comment: Hi Jeremy, thanks for the help but it says 

    message = (f'From:  myself<me@test.com>\n'
                                                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Hi ! Sorry I should have asked you your python version, f-string are only available in python>=3.6 . I've edited my answer to add the old school python string formatting, hopefully this should work ;)

Comment: thank you so much @jeremy for the help again! Have tested it again but the email body message is still empty :S

Comment: Could you try the edited version and tell me if this is working ?

Comment: Hi Jeremy, i found the issue before you edit the code. you need to have a line spacing between Subject and the body message for it to display in the email body :) Thanks it works now! Will upvote your answer. Cheers!

Comment: Great ! No problem. Could you check if the edit is ok now or change it exactly as it is (without #edited by) ?